# To remove duplicate elements in an array and only show unique one

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, for-loop, nested-loops

I made a program to remove duplicate elements in an array, but it is not working correctly. Can someone help me with it? When I input `1,1,1,2,3` it displays `1,1,2,3`.

It works fine with other inputs, but only shows an error when I enter input with multiple `1`s.

```cpp
//To remove duplicacy of the elements
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"Enter the number of elements in your array:"<<endl;
    int s;
    cin>>s;
    int arr[s];
    for (int i=0;i<s;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter the element at position "<<i<<endl;
        cin>>arr[i];
    }
    cout<<"Your array is"<<endl;
    for (int i=0;i<s;i++)
    {
        cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0;i<s-count;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1;j<s-count;j++)
        {
            if (arr[i]==arr[j])
            {
                for(int i=j;i<s-count;i++)
                {
                    arr[i]=arr[i+1];
                }
                count++;
            }
        }
    }

    cout<<"Your array after removing duplicacy now is"<<endl;
    for (int i=0;i<s-count;i++)
        {
            cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is the input already known to be sorted? It is important. If the array is already sorted you don't need an O(N^2) algorithm to do this; you can do it in O(N). If it is *not* sorted you can sort it in O(NlogN), and then still finish it with an additional O(N) (so still O(NlogN) overall). Regardless, single stepping your code *in a debugger*  with the trivial input you've shown here will be revealing.

Comment: If you're permitted to, `std::unique` can do the heavy lifting instead

Comment: `int arr[s];` isn't valid c++. It's a gcc/g++ extension.

Answer (score 0):

In these nested for loops

```
for(int i=0;i<s-count;i++)
{
    for(int j=i+1;j<s-count;j++)
    {
        if (arr[i]==arr[j])
        {
            for(int i=j;i<s-count;i++)
            {
                arr[i]=arr[i+1];
            }
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

if the array has or example three adjacent elements with the same value then after this loop

```
for(int i=j;i<s-count;i++)
{
    arr[i]=arr[i+1];
}
```

there will be two adjacent elements. But as the index i is incremented in the outer for loop then the second adjacent element will stay in the array because only elements after it are traversed in the second for loop.

Pay attention to that variable length arrays are not a standard C++ feature. Instead use standard container `std::vector`.

Actually the used approach is inefficient because all elements starting from the found duplicate element are moved. A more efficient approach can look the following way as shown in the demonstration program below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 1, 1, 2, 3 };

    for (const auto &item : v)
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    size_t k = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        size_t j = 0;
        while (j != k && v[j] != v[i]) j++;

        if (j == k)
        {
            if ( k != i )
            {
                v[k] = v[i];
            }
            ++k;
        }
    }

    if (k != v.size())
    {
        v.erase( std::next( std::begin( v ), k ), std::end( v ) );
    }

    for (const auto &item : v)
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The program output is:

```
1 1 1 2 3
1 2 3
```

Of course instead of using indices and the subscript operator it is better to use iterators.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 1, 1, 2, 3 };

    for (const auto &item : v)
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    auto result = std::begin( v );

    for ( auto current = std::begin( v ), last = std::end( v ); current != last; ++current )
    {
        if (std::find( std::begin( v ), result, *current ) == result)
        {
            if (result != current)
            {
                *result = *current;
            }
            ++result;
        }
    }
        

    v.erase( result, std::end( v ) );

    for (const auto &item : v)
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: is there any way I can run that loop again to remove the other second repeated element incase of 3 adjacent elements???

Comment: @Divyam You could not increase the index i in this case when a duplicate was removed. But actually this approach is inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the problem was with the operation in your deletion loops, when you are deleting an element in the array, you need to decrement the size accordingly.

```
for (int i = 0; i < s; ++i)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < s;)
    {
        if (arr[i] == arr[j])
        {
            for (int k = j; k < s - 1; ++k)
                arr[k] = arr[k + 1];
            --s;
        }
        else
            ++j;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problematic section:

```
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0;i<s-count;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1;j<s-count;j++)
        {
            if (arr[i]==arr[j])
            {
                for(int i=j;i<s-count;i++)
                {
                    arr[i]=arr[i+1];
                }
                count++;
            }
        }
```

The problem is that `i` always moves which makes any nonunique cosecutive sequence of length > 2 undetectable.
Here is the replacement, adopted from the example implementation [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique):

```
    int i = 0;
    int j = i;
    for(++i; i < s; ++i)
    {
        if (!(arr[j] == arr[i]) && !(++j == i)) {
            arr[j] = arr[i];
        }
    }
    ++j;
    cout<<"Your array after removing duplicacy now is"<<endl;
    for (int i=0;i<j;i++)
        {
            cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
        }
    return 0;
```

Additionally, there are further advanges to this:

1. Linear time-complexity
2. No restriction with regards to random-access / bidirectional iterator. Only forward iterators are required (of course, the current implementation makes direct use of random-access containers)

Answer (score -1):

To make your code more efficient you can use XOR(^) it will remove two same numbers with better time complexity.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).